# displaying content of <script type="text/html"

Tags: javascript, php

I have a php file that contains the following script:

```
<script type="text/html" id="thisId">
  //SOME HTML and code strting with <#
</script>
```

When I include this file inside another php file nothing shows up. What do I do?

Edit: I tried removing script tag but the part inside <# doesn't show up correctly.

Comment: So what do I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<script>` tag contents are hidden by default no matter the type you set

You could set the style of the element so that it is visible, ie `display:block`. But the contents will not be rendered as HTML. So if you just want to display the text you can just do this.

But if you want the content to actually be shown and rendered as HTML you will need to copy the contents to some other container:

```js
var script = document.getElementById("template");
var target = document.getElementById("target");

target.innerHTML = script.textContent;
```

```html
<script type="text/html" id="template">
  <h1>Some html</h1>
</script>

<div id="target"></div>
```

Comment: That's great but what about the part inside <# tag. It comes up without rendering and scaped like this: <# if ( typeof data.qty !== 'undefined' ) { #>

Comment: @user7432810 is that some sort of library framework (like a template engine) markup? If so you would have to make sure that text goes through that framework first to get processed

Comment: This is a page of a wordpress plugin. At first I thought it would be easy to just include it but apparently there is more to it.

Comment: Thanks Patrick. The "template engine" you suggested made me go deeper and found out it is actually part of the plugin that cannot directly called.